# Issue while building Xamarin.android

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, firebase, xamarin.forms

I'm currently building a Xamarin APP, but recently it's totally impossible to buid my app on android.
Visual Studio return me this issue :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       MSB4062: The "Xamarin.Build.Download.XamarinBuildAndroidAarRestore" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\name\.nuget\packages\xamarin.build.download\0.4.9\build\Xamarin.Build.Download.dll.  Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.          0
```

What i've tried to do :

- Clean and build the android project and the entire project
- Unload and load the android project
- Remove .vs/ folder
- Repair Visual Studio 2019 via Installer (this work fine once)
- Restart Visual Studio / PC

The nugget i've installed :

- Xamarin Forms on core project - Android - iOS (v 4.6.0.847)
- Xamarin Essential on core project - Android - iOS (v 1.5.3.2)
- Xamarin Firebase Auth on core project - Android (v 60.1142.1)
- Xamarin Firebase Core on core project - Android (v 60.1142.1)

Comment: Can you please try to install/update Xamarin.Build.Download in your .Android porject?

Comment: Hi, it's work with your solution, thanks a lot

Comment: I just added an answer, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

Install/update Xamarin.Build.Download in your .Android project.